# two BoxSizers interfere

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I have two BoxSizers, the first one

```
sizer = wx.BoxSizer (wx.VERTICAL)
sizer.Add (self.grid2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
panel2.SetSizer (sizer)
```

and another vertical BoxSizers, to the left of the button grid, both BoxSizers interfere.

```
vbox1 = wx.FlexGridSizer (rows = 1, cols = 3, hgap = 5, vgap = 5)
buttonsBox1 = wx.BoxSizer (wx.VERTICAL)
buttonsBox1.Add (self.buttonoborved)
vbox1.Add (buttonsBox1)
vbox1.Add (self.grid2)
vbox1.Add (midPan1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)
panel2.SetSizer (vbox1)
```

An error occurs - Adding a window already in a sizer, detach it first!
How can they be called at the same time.

Edit:
That are two BoxSizer, one in other, but how can be put buttons in there.

```
import wx
import wx.grid
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel

class TestPanel(ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
    ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, size=(640, 480))
    self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.sizer.Add(self._create_table(), 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
    self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
    self.SetupScrolling()
    self.SetAutoLayout(1)

def _create_table(self):
    _table = wx.grid.Grid(self, -1)
    _table.CreateGrid(0, 2)
    for i in range(1723):  # Work normally If I use 1722 rows
        _table.AppendRows()
        _table.SetCellValue(i, 0, str(i))
    return _table

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
            title="Scroll table", size=(640, 480))
    self.fSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.fSizer.Add(TestPanel(self), 1, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(self.fSizer)
    self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = TestFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You are adding `self.grid2` to both sizers. Decide which one it should be in, "there can be only one" ;) The `sizer` containing `self.grid2` can be placed in another sizer. Think of sizers as boxes. Boxes can go in other boxes but you can't put 1 item in more than 1 box.

Comment: I used buttonsBox1 = wx.BoxSizer (wx.VERTICAL) to add buttons to wxgrid and coud’t find another way to make this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends where you want to place the buttons but let's assume they should be at the bottom.

```
import wx
import wx.grid
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel

class TestPanel(ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, size=(640, 480))
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self._create_table(), 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.b1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Button 1")
        self.b2 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Button 2")
        self.b3 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Button 3")

        button_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        button_sizer.Add(self.b1)
        button_sizer.Add(self.b2)
        button_sizer.Add(self.b3)
        self.sizer.Add(button_sizer)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.SetupScrolling()
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)

    def _create_table(self):
        _table = wx.grid.Grid(self, -1)
        _table.CreateGrid(0, 2)
        for i in range(1723):  # Work normally If I use 1722 rows
            _table.AppendRows()
            _table.SetCellValue(i, 0, str(i))
        return _table

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                title="Scroll table", size=(640, 480))
        self.fSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.fSizer.Add(TestPanel(self), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.fSizer)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = TestFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: @Dimitar You should see beside the answer a tick icon and some up and down arrows. If an answer specifically solved your problem to your satisfaction `Accept` the answer by clicking the Tick icon. If the answer was useful, click the Up arrow. If the answer was not helpful at all, Click the Down arrow. Welcome to StackOverflow.